# How to make a boolean variable from a summary statistic in a dataframe?

Tags: r, boolean, max, sapply, tapply

I want to make a boolean column which states whether or not each sample is a maximum.
I made this function and used it with `tapply`:

```
is.max <- function(x){
  x <- data.frame(x)
  x$x <- round(x$x,5)
  x_max <- round(max(x),5)
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if(x$x[i] == x_max) x$is.max[i] <- T
    else x$is.max[i] <- F
  }
return(x$is.max)
}

y <- c(rnorm(10), runif(10), rnorm(10,1))
f <- gl(3,10)
m <- tapply(y,f,is.max)
```

But is there a better, efficient way to do that?

{P.S. Actually with my real data I used `sapply`, e.g. `is.maxes<-sapply(s, function(x) is.max(x[,"Sum"]),simplify=F)`}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use do this in one line with `tapply`:

```
tapply(y,f,function(x) round(x,5)==round(max(x),5))
```